# Django filtered queryset in foreignkey lookup

Tags: django

I have a standard model with a foreignkey, in this case from biology: Seed to Taxon. The taxon model includes both Animal and Plant Taxon, and has a category column which is either zoology or botany

When I add a new Seed I get the expected dropdown list, but it supplies the zoology and botany options. How do I filter it so only the botany options are shown? I'm assuming this filter can be applied somewhere in the model? I've tried adding .filter() and .exclude() but they do nothing here.

```
class Taxon(models.Model):
    taxon_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    taxon = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    common_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    taxon = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    genus = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    # family_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.taxon)

    class Meta():
        managed=False
        db_table = 'kap\".\"taxon_manager'
        ordering = ["genus","taxon"]
        verbose_name_plural = "taxon"

class Seed(models.Model):
    seed_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fraction_id = models.ForeignKey(Fraction, db_column='fraction_id', blank=True, null=True, on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    taxon_id = models.ForeignKey(Taxon, db_column='taxon_id', blank=True, null=True, on_delete = models.PROTECT, related_name='seed_taxon')
    weight_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
    quantity_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.taxon_id)

    class Meta():
        managed=False
        db_table = 'kap\".\"seed'
        ordering = ["taxon_id","fraction_id"]
        verbose_name_plural = "seeds"
```

Comment: What did you try with filter?

Comment: return str(self.taxon_id.filter(category='botany'))
in the way you would normally add a filter in a view.

Comment: How about .filter(taxon__category='botany')  instead

Comment: Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'filter'

Comment: You should be filtering on a queryset, not on `taxon_id`. So, something like `Taxon.objects.all().filter(taxon__category='botany')`. I also wouldn't wrap this with `str()`.

Answer (score 0):

If the `category` field in your `Taxon` model is a choice between "zoology" and "botany", then I would make them choices like so:

```
class Taxon(models.Model):

   ZOOLOGY = 0
   BOTANY = 1

   CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
       (ZOOLOGY, 'Zoology'),
       (BOTANY, 'Botany'),
   )

   <your other fields>
   category = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
```

Then, if you want to filter inside your `seed` model, you could change your `taxon_id` field so that it includes [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to):

```
taxon_id = models.ForeignKey(
             Taxon, 
             db_column='taxon_id', 
             limit_choices_to={'category': Taxon.BOTANY},
             blank=True, 
             null=True, 
             on_delete = models.PROTECT, 
             related_name='seed_taxon'
)
```

I haven't explicitly tested this case, but something like the above should work. If you want to filter in other places, then the `filter` that Juan mentioned in the comment looks good.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks close, in my case the Zoology or Botany choice is added automatically based on the app the person is using - the Zoology app or the Botany app. So obviously I don't want the Zoology person seeing plant taxa etc. 

Your example returns the error: 'Taxon' has no attribute 'Botany'

Comment: Ahh, that's probably the incorrect casing - should be `Taxon.BOTANY` instead of `Taxon.Botany` (just edited).

Comment: I tried both uppercase and lower case: 
AttributeError: type object 'Taxon' has no attribute 'Botany' and AttributeError: type object 'Taxon' has no attribute 'BOTANY'

Comment: Did you create the `BOTANY = 1` field in your Taxon model? If not, and you left it as before without the `choices` attribute, then you'd have to do something like `{'category': 'botany'}`.